# Why does my Node.js gRPC client take 3 seconds to send a request to my Python gRPC server?

Tags: python, node.js, electron, grpc-python, grpc-node

Let's begin by acknowledging that I am a gRPC noob. If I've asked a stupid question, go ahead and let me know, but only after *explaining* why it's stupid. Thanks! :)

### **Overview**

I am developing an application that processes images. The variables that affect the result of the processing are to be changeable by the user. I wanted to provide a good-looking GUI while maintaining cross-platform compatibility. Thus, I decided to implement my image processing in Python, and use Node.js and Electron for my GUI.

Needing a way to send and receive data to and from my Python backend, I decided to use gRPC. Thus I have a **Node.js gRPC Client** paired with a **Python gRPC Server**.

After reading through many tutorials and learning a bit about protocol buffers, I was able to successfully transfer data between the two programs.

### **The Setup**

The Node.js Electron app takes input from the user, and sends a request to the Python backend. The size of the request is a small object:

```js
// From My Protocol Buffer
message DetectionSettings {
    float lowerThreshold = 1;
    float upperThreshold = 2;
    float smallestObject = 3;
    float largestObject  = 4;
    float blurAmount     = 5;

    int64 frameNumber    = 6;
    string streamSource  = 7;
}
```

Upon receiving this request, the Python application reads a frame from the specified `streamSource` and processes it. This processed frame is then converted to JPEG format and returned via gRPC to the Node.js app as an `Image`:

```js
// From My Protocol Buffer
message Image {
    bytes image_data = 1;
    int32 height = 2;
    int32 width = 3;
    int64 frame = 4;    
}
```

### The Problem

I've noticed that there is a variable latency between the time the request is made and the image is received. This time varies from a few ms up to nearly 3 SECONDS! After profiling the Python code, I've determined that the processing time is negligible. In addition, the time that it takes to return the `Image` via gRPC is also negligible.

Thus there is an intriguing delay between the RPC execution and the Python application receiving the call. Here are some logs with the times to better explain what's happening (The number in brackets is in seconds):

```js
/* Node.js */
[160408.072] "Sending Request..."
[160408.072] "Executing RPC"
[160408.072] "RPC Executed"

/* Python */
[160411.032] [ py-backend ] Getting frame

/* Node.js */
[160411.617] "Got Data"
```

You can see that in this case the time from Node.js RPC execution to the Python method being called was around 3 seconds, while the time from the execution of the Python method to the Node.js application receiving the `Image` is less than 1 second 0.o

### The Code

Python gRPC Server

```py
# Create the server
server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))

# Add our service to the server
processor_pb2_grpc.add_ProcessorServicer_to_server(
    ProcessorServicer(), server
)

server.add_insecure_port('[::1]:50053')
server.start()
server.wait_for_termination()
```

Node.js Client:

```js
const grpc = require('grpc')
const PROTO_PATH = '../processor.proto'

const serviceConfig = {
    "loadBalancingConfig": [ {"round_robin": {} } ]
}
const options = {
    'grpc.service_config': JSON.stringify(serviceConfig)
}

const ProcessorService = grpc.load(PROTO_PATH).Processor
const client = new ProcessorService ('[::1]:50053',
    grpc.credentials.createInsecure(), options);

module.exports = client
```

Protocol Buffer:

```js
syntax = "proto3";

message Number {
    float value = 1;
}

message Image {
    bytes image_data = 1;
    int32 height = 2;
    int32 width = 3;
    int64 frame = 4;    
}

message DetectionSettings {
    float lowerThreshold = 1;
    float upperThreshold = 2;
    float smallestObject = 3;
    float largestObject  = 4;
    float blurAmount     = 5;

    int64 frameNumber    = 6;
    string streamSource  = 7;
}

service Processor{
    rpc GetFrame(DetectionSettings) returns (Image) {};
}
```

Node.js gRPC Call:

```js
function GetFrameBytes(detectionSettings, streamSource, frameNumber, callback)
{
    detectionSettings["streamSource"] = streamSource;
    detectionSettings["frameNumber"] = frameNumber;

    client.GetFrame(detectionSettings, (error, response) =>
    {
        if(!error){
            callback(response)
        }
        else
        {
            console.error(error);
        }
    });
}
```

### tl;dr

Why on earth does it take so long for my Node.js client request to trigger my Python code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of factors that could be impacting the long time you are seeing.

First, the first request made by a client always takes longer because it has to do some connection setup work. The general expectation is that a single client will make many requests, and that the setup time will be amortized over all of those requests.

Second, you mentioned that you are using Electron. There have been some reports of gRPC for Node performing poorly when used in the Electron rendering process. You may see different results when running your code in the main process, or in a regular Node process.

You may also have different luck if you try the package `@grpc/grpc-js`, which is a complete reimplementation of the Node gRPC library. The API you are currently using for loading the `.proto` packages does not exist in that library, but the alternative using `@grpc/proto-loader` works with both implementations, and the other APIs are the same.

Comment: Thank you for your insightful answer! I tested the 'first request takes longer' theory by continuously making connections. This resulted in a massive speed-up.

Although I'm a bit confused still...are connections being 'dropped' after a timeout period? Or why does simply running my code with less time between the requests make the response faster?

Comment: I just want to clarify, when you make a request with a client `client.methodName(...)`, you are usually not making new connections, you are using existing connections that the client manages internally. That is why requests after the first are faster.

Comment: If you wait long enough between requests, the underlying connection might get closed for inactivity, so it will need to be recreated when you make the next request.

Comment: Ah I see. I had a delay of ~1s between requests. It was only once I reduced the delay to 0 (immediately send another request once the response is received) that I noticed an improvement.

Comment: It's surprising to me that the connection would go away after only a second, but I'm not sure of the details there.

Comment: @murgatroid99 are there any recommended mechanisms for mitigating initial request time? For example, adding some kind of "ping/pong" to all of your services and having the client call a ping to get the initial connection setup before the first user-initiated call? Or is there some configuration you can use to like "setup connection before initial request"?

Comment: The client has a method `waitForReady` that will instruct it to start connecting, and call the callback when a connection has been established. That would serve the same purpose as the "ping/pong" method you mentioned: setting up the connection before you need to use it. I do want to make sure it's clear that this doesn't change how long it will take to establish the connection, just when it happens. If you want to make a request immediately after constructing the client, you might as well just make that request.

Comment: @murgatroid99 On the JS side, if I call waitForReady on a client before ever making a request to that client, I still see the same overhead when making the initial request (aka setup is still happening). I was under the impression your comment meant that calling waitForReady would serve as a warmup call, like ping-pong?

Comment: I do mean that `waitForReady` works the same as a warmup call, in terms of establishing a connection before the request you actually want to make. Are you waiting for the `waitForReady` callback to be called (without an error) before making the request? If you are and you are still experiencing that initial request delay, that is a bug and I suggest filing an issue on the library's [GitHub repository](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node).

Comment: Yes, I am calling waitForReady right after instantiating the JS client, and then a few moments later, clicking a button that makes the initial request, which takes about 40s, and then clicking the same button subsequently takes 4ms. I will file an issue on github - thanks for your help!

Comment: Just to be completely clear, when you say "a few moments later", do you mean that you are passing a callback as an argument to `waitForReady` and you are waiting for that callback to be called before making the initial request? Are you checking whether that callback was called with an error? Are you passing a deadline to `waitForReady` that is far enough in the future that it will actually wait long enough for the connection to be established?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229666/discussion-between-netpoetica-and-murgatroid99).